# Facebook Access token expires in two hours

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for the facebook feeds of microsoft ..but problem is that Facebook Access token expires in two hours. is there any way to get access token which does not expires after two hours.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Microsoft/posts?access_token=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Info about Access Tokens, including "Extended Tokens":

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

BUT: For getting the feed of a Facebook Page, you only need an App Access Token, and that one is valid forever. See the links about that Token, it´s quite easy: "`APP-ID|APP-SECRET`" - just don´t put it in client code, the secret should never be visible to the User.

For Microsoft, this would be the endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Microsoft/feed?access_token=App-ID|App-Secret
```

Comment: u mean to say i should use `https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret` but where how do i use `https://graph.facebook.com/Microsoft/posts?access_token=` to get feeds

Comment: it is /feed, not /posts. i will edit my answer.

Comment: this is definitely not working with either app id or app secret ... genertated on developer facebook app

Comment: giving me message: "Invalid OAuth access token."error

Comment: i just tried in the graph api explorer by putting in an app-id|app-secret combination from one of my apps, it works perfectly fine. please use exactly that combination: app-id > pipe sign > app-secret

Comment: also tried it directly in the browser, works 100%.

Comment: Thanks that works.. I was trying only once not both the things,.. thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Expiration and Extending Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) documentation on Facebook Developers. I guess this will solve your problem.

Comment: not working .. do u know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

in FB.init:

```
FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxx', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//yourdomain/channel.php', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        frictionlessRequests: true, // enable frictionless requests     
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });
```

where channelUrl is:

```
<?php
$cache_expire = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=" . $cache_expire);
header("Expires:" . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $cache_expire) . " GMT");
?>

<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

that should make the connection open for one year due to cache-control